# Service Broker is not starting

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

ALTER DATABASE [Database Name] SET ENABLE_BROKER; Does not respond, and works infinitely. SQL Agent service is running, what is chances?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How long should I expect ALTER DATABASE … SET ENABLE_BROKER to run?](http://rusanu.com/2006/01/30/how-long-should-i-expect-alter-databse-set-enable_broker-to-run/)

`ALTER DATABASE ... SET ENABLE_BROKER` requires exclusive access on the database and it will block if there is any other session in the database. To force it, you can use the `WITH ROLLBACK` clause that will kill any session that blocks your `ALTE`R:

```
ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should kill all processes for that Database first. Here is how to do.

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/kill-all-processes-of-a-database.aspx